# How can I make a python candlestick chart clickable in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, interactive

I am trying to make a OHLC graph plotted with matplotlib interactive upon the user clicking on a valid point. The data is stored as a pandas dataframe of the form

```
index       PX_BID  PX_ASK  PX_LAST  PX_OPEN  PX_HIGH  PX_LOW
2016-07-01  1.1136  1.1137   1.1136   1.1106   1.1169  1.1072
2016-07-04  1.1154  1.1155   1.1154   1.1143   1.1160  1.1098
2016-07-05  1.1076  1.1077   1.1076   1.1154   1.1186  1.1062
2016-07-06  1.1100  1.1101   1.1100   1.1076   1.1112  1.1029
2016-07-07  1.1062  1.1063   1.1063   1.1100   1.1107  1.1053
```

I am plotting it with matplotlib's candlestick function:

```
candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, df['PX_OPEN'],df['PX_HIGH'],df['PX_LOW'],df['PX_LAST'],width=1)
```

When plotted it looks somthing like this:

https://pythonprogramming.net/static/images/matplotlib/candlestick-ohlc-graphs-matplotlib-tutorial.png

I want the console to print out the value of the point clicked, the date and whether it is an open, high low or close. So far I have something like:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_title('click on points', picker=True)
ax1.set_ylabel('ylabel', picker=True, bbox=dict(facecolor='red'))
line = candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, df['PX_OPEN'],df['PX_HIGH'],df['PX_LOW'],df['PX_LAST'],width=0.4)

def onpick1(event):
    if isinstance(event.artist, (lineCollection, barCollection)):
        thisline = event.artist
        xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
        ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
        ind = event.ind
        #points = tuple(zip(xdata[ind], ydata[ind]))
        #print('onpick points:', points)
        print( 'X='+str(np.take(xdata, ind)[0]) ) # Print X point
        print( 'Y='+str(np.take(ydata, ind)[0]) ) # Print Y point

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
plt.show()
```

This code however does not print anything when ran and points are clicked. When I look at examples of interactive matplotlib graphs, they tend to have an argument in the plot function such as:

```
line, = ax.plot(rand(100), 'o', picker=5)
```

However, candlestick2_ohlc does not take a 'picker' arg. Any tips on how I can get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `set_picker(True)` to enable a pick event  or give a tolerance in points as a float (see http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_picker).

So in your case `ax1.set_picker(True)` if you want  pick event to be fired whenever if mouseevent is over `ax1`.

You can enable pick events on the elements of the candlestick chart. I read the documentation and [`candlestick2_ohlc`](http://matplotlib.org/api/finance_api.html#matplotlib.finance.candlestick2_ohlc) returns a tuple of two objects: a `LineCollection` and a `PolyCollection`. So you can name these objects and set the picker to true on them

```
(lines,polys) = candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, ...)
lines.set_picker(True) # collection of lines in the candlestick chart
polys.set_picker(True) # collection of polygons in the candlestick chart
```

The index of the event `ind = event.ind[0]` will tell you which element in the collection contained the mouse event (`event.ind` returns a list of indices since a mouse event might pertain more than one item).

Once you trigger a pick event on a candlestick you can print the data from the original dataframe.

Here's some working code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PolyCollection
from matplotlib.text import Text
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range('20160101',periods=7)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(1+np.random.random_sample(42)*0.1,(7,6)),index=dates,columns=["PX_BID","PX_ASK","PX_LAST","PX_OPEN","PX_HIGH","PX_LOW"])
df['PX_HIGH']+=.1
df['PX_LOW']-=.1

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.set_title('click on points', picker=20)
ax1.set_ylabel('ylabel', picker=20, bbox=dict(facecolor='red'))

(lines,polys) = candlestick2_ohlc(ax1, df['PX_OPEN'],df['PX_HIGH'],df['PX_LOW'],df['PX_LAST'],width=0.4)
lines.set_picker(True)
polys.set_picker(True)

def onpick1(event):
    if isinstance(event.artist, (Text)):
        text = event.artist
        print 'You clicked on the title ("%s")' % text.get_text()
    elif isinstance(event.artist, (LineCollection, PolyCollection)):   
        thisline = event.artist
        mouseevent = event.mouseevent
        ind = event.ind[0]
        print 'You clicked on item %d' % ind
        print 'Day: ' + df.index[ind].normalize().to_datetime().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        for p in ['PX_OPEN','PX_OPEN','PX_HIGH','PX_LOW']:
            print p + ':' + str(df[p][ind])    
        print('x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ( mouseevent.x, mouseevent.y, mouseevent.xdata, mouseevent.ydata))



fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, however this leads to error:

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_xdata'

Any ideas?